# Does a pull request on github automatically create an associated issue?

Tags: git, github

Should I open an issue first to ask about modifying certain files, or can I just go right ahead and make the modifications on my branch and send a pull request? I assume that discussions would necessarily need to follow in an issue thread. Does the pull request itself automatically initiate an issue, or is that something that I will need to initiate and reference the pull request in the issue?

Comment: If my memory serves me correctly, then creating a pull request will not automatically create an issue.  Whether or not you want to link your PR to an issue is up to your team's standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, a pull request (PR) on Github does NOT create an related issue. In terms of whether you should create an issue depends on the policy of the repository you are sending the PR to. If it is a large PR or a PR with controversial changes, it probably is better to create an issue for it first and wait for some feedback.